# Noncollinear band structure calculation with VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, condensed-matter, dft-u

I am trying to do a band structure calculation of a noncollinear magnetic system. I am getting results that are nowhere close to what I'm expecting. I need help checking if I am following the right procedure:

1. The relaxation step is skipped (using the experimental value for the crystal structure)
2. A self-consistency calculation with SOC and Hubbard-U correction.
3. A band structure calculation using the `CHGCAR` file obtained from the previous step.

The `INCAR` files that I used for both runs are:

- For the self-consistent calculation:

  ```
  ISTART = 0

  ISMEAR = 0
  SIGMA = 0.05

  IBRION = -1
  NSW = 0

  PREC = Normal
  ENCUT = 300 eV
  NELM = 200
  EDIFF = 1E-6

  NBANDS = 120

  LSORBIT = .TRUE.
  ISPIN = 2
  MAGMOM = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -2.7 0 0 2.7
  GGA_COMPAT = .FALSE.
  ISYM =-1

  LDAU=.TRUE.
  LDAUTYPE = 3
  LDAUL = -1 3 
  LDAUU = 0 6.3 
  LDAUJ = 0 0.7 
  LMAXMIX = 6
  LDAUPRINT = 1
  ```
- For the band structure calculation:

  ```
  ISTART = 1
  ICHARG = 11

  ISMEAR = 0
  SIGMA = 0.05

  PREC = Normal
  ENCUT = 300 eV
  NELM = 200
  EDIFF = 1E-6

  NBANDS = 120

  LORBIT = 11


  LSORBIT = .TRUE.
  ISPIN = 2
  SAXIS =  0 0 1
  MAGMOM = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -2.7 0 0 2.7
  GGA_COMPAT = .FALSE.
  ISYM =-1

  LDAU=.TRUE.
  LDAUTYPE = 3
  LDAUL = -1 3 
  LDAUU = 0 6.3 
  LDAUJ = 0 0.7 
  LMAXMIX = 6
  LDAUPRINT = 1
  ```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nani, welcome to the Matter Modeling community! For us to be able to help you, could you please elaborate on the issue? i.e., what is your expectation, what are you getting right now with these inputs? Thanks!

Comment: remove the quantum espresso tag if you haven't mentioned it in the question